# Assign to a variable whose name is stored in another variable in bash

Tags: string, bash, variables

How to assign to a variable whose name is stored in another variable in bash? Something like (the example does not work):

```
foo=1    
a='foo'
$a=42    # This does not work:"bash: foo=42: command not found"
# Want foo == 42 here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
eval "$a=42"
```

For example:

```
$ a=foo
$ eval "$a=42"
$ echo $foo
42
```

Comment: Using `eval` is dangerous. If `a='date; foo'` then it will execute `date` command before assigning `42` to `foo`. Now imagine if `date` is replaced by some `rm` command.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, `eval` is dangerous - you have to be able to trust where `a` comes from (among other things); this may be OK if it is guaranteed to come from your own script. Unfortunately `declare` is not available in all shells, though the question is about `bash` so it can be used here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `declare` directive:

```
declare -- $a=42
```

Check content of `foo`:

```
declare -p foo
declare -- foo="42"

echo "$foo"
42
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`. For example:

```
var1=abc

eval $var1="value1"   # abc set to value1
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted more than the excepted answer. It was created after